# How can I access the weakref object of the class itself through the class?

Tags: python, class, weak-references, python-internals, python-datamodel

As far as I know, `__weakref__` is a descriptor defined in class, so that if it invoked from the instances of the class, it will give the `weakref` object:

```py
from weakref import ref

class A:
    pass

obj = A()
wr = ref(obj)
print(obj.__weakref__ is wr)  # True
```

What about the class `A` itself? the metaclass `type` doesn't have `__weakref__` descriptor:

```py
print("__weakref__" in type.__dict__)  # False
```

Why `type` metaclass doesn't have that descriptor? then where is it stored? how is it possible to access the `weakref` object (here `wr_of_A`) from the class?

```py
from weakref import ref

class A:
    pass

wr_of_A = ref(A)
print(A.__weakref__)

# <attribute '__weakref__' of 'A' objects>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the `__weakref__` attribute is exposed in Python as part of the mechanism to allow user created classes be able to opt if they are weak-refereanceble or not as documented in the [`__slots__` text on the data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Other than that, even its content being the weakref for the instance seens to be an implementation detail - no other reference to `__weakref__` is made on the data model document - which is as a "canonical spec"  of Python objetcs as one can get. In the C implementation it is likely the `__weakref__` descriptor uses the object's [`tp_weaklistoffset` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_weaklistoffset) (in the in memory object structure) to retrieve a weakreference object (sorry, I did not dig into the code to check that).

However, when one goes to type instances, they use the [`tp_weaklist` slot](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_weaklist) to point to its weak references, using a mechanism that is marked for internal use only, and not exposed to the Python side at all.

In short: if you are dealing with weakreferences, always use the functions in the `weakref` module.